# How can I delete dynamically created objects in jQuery after the user "starts over" on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have an autocomplete combobox that creates a new select box based upon the value selected. However, if the user clicks back on the autocomplete box and does another search, an *additional* select box is created.

I need to somehow remove the select box if the user does an additional search. Would I do that in the `onFocus` event?

Comment: can't you remove old select boxes at the point you create a new one?

Comment: funnily enough, i almost requested "specifics and code" from the OP - chose instead to answer in the style the question was asked.. but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the class of the new select boxes you create to `class="dynamic"`.
Then, in the same event in which you create the new select box add:

```
$('.dynamic').remove();
```

to remove all the select boxes you created before.

Answer (score 1):

Use a new variable for 2nd combo i.e.

```
var combo2shown = false;
```

When it is created set the new variable to 'true'.

Finally, add validation to your method e.g.

```
if (combo2shown) {
    //dont create again
} else {
    combo2shown = true;
    //create second combo
}
```